# Converting DateTime to DateTime? causing error in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

In my c# code behind, when I convert
`public DateTime custDOB { get; set; }`
to
`public DateTime? SubDOB { get; set; }`

I get an error on one of my code lines
`tboxDateOfBirth.Text = oCust.custDOB.ToShortDateString();`

and the message reads **'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for 'ToShortDateString' and no extension method 'ToShortDateString' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable' could be found**

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Although the resolution to your problem is quite simple, the wording is quite confusing. Change the type of `custDOB` to `DateTime?` in your first code line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change that line to

```
tboxDateOfBirth.Text = oCust.custDOB.HasValue? oCust.custDOB.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are at all time 100% sure that it will have a value and will not be null do this

```
tboxDateOfBirth.Text = ((DateTime)(oCust.custDOB)).ToShortDateString();
```

or if there are chances that it can be null you can go for Andre Calil answer.

Also you should read about [null-coalescing operator (??)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

Comment: I don't think you can use the ?? operator here since it only allows us to manipulate what to do when the value is null.

Answer (score 1):

There is nullable types - like int? or DateTime?, so you can check, if they have any value with `.HasValue`
To access actual value use

```
oCust.custDOB.Value.ToShortDateString();
```